# Pandas dataframe mutability with loc method

Tags: python, pandas, mutable

I am trying to understand the inticacies of using `loc` on a dataframe. Suppose we have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df2 = df.loc[:,'a']
df2.loc[0] = 10
print(df)
print(df2)

    a  b
0  10  4
1   2  5
2   3  6
0    10
1     2
2     3
Name: a, dtype: int64


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df3 = df.loc[:,['a']]
df3.loc[0] = 10
print(df)
print(df3)

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
    a
0  10
1   2
2   3
```

Why does the first piece of code modify the original dataframe, whereas the second does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your first code, `df2` is a view of `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df2 = df.loc[:,'a']

df2._is_view
# True
```

Use `copy` to ensure having a copy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df2 = df.loc[:,'a'].copy()

df2._is_view
# False
```

##### why?

Because in the first case the slice is a Series (1D object) and in the second a DataFrame (2D):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

df.loc[:,'a'].shape
# (3,)  -> this is 1D (Series)
df.loc[:,'a'].ndim
# 1

df.loc[:,['a']].shape
# (3,1) -> this is 2D (DataFrame)
df.loc[:,['a']].ndim
# 2
```

Comment: I understand that. But why does simply putting ```'a'``` in brackets result in a copy instead of a view?

Comment: Because you're slicing a 1D object out of the DataFrame, vs a 2D object (with a single item in the second dimension) in the second code. I added some details